# How to Transcribe A Word That The Speaker Doesn't Known

Tags: homophones, transcription

When transcribing spoken dialogues between individuals, what do we write if the words are ambiguous?

Example 1:

> Hyun: How do you spell witch in English?
>
> Jim: Which '**which**' are you asking about?

(Is the second 'which' the right choice?)

Example 2:

> Teacher: In English, homophones are words that sound the same but have different spellings. For example, we have three different words for **too**: 'two' the number, 'too' meaning 'in addition', and 'to' as a verb.

(The speaker isn't referring to the word 'too'. They are referring to the sound /to͞o/. It would seem odd to have a pronunciation there though.)

Comment: I'd be suspicious of any teacher who classes *to* as a verb.

Comment: It's a tough problem.  The best thing you can do, I think, is transcribe it as the most likely or most common word.

Comment: @verbose: probably meant **to** as an infinitive marker, though that would usually be pronounced as a weak form /tʊ/ /tu/ /tə/ which would not sound like two or too /tuː/.

Comment: @verbose *Adverb ;)

Comment: It's not an adverb either. It's a preposition.

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/to describes it as an adverb in addition to a preposition. Merriam Webster describes it similarly.

Answer (score 1):

In example 1, Jim doesn't need to repeat the sound: he could easily explain by referring to the distinct meanings, for example:

> Jim: Do you want the spelling for "which cake do you want?" or for "the witch cast a spell"?

As for example 2: if it's spoken, the issue doesn't arise, and if it's written, then phonemic script /tuː/ would be the clearest way of explaining. The context of the following words should help those people that can't read phonemic script.